# Check if all element except the first has a certain class

Tags: jquery

I want to check if all elements (except the first) of a container have a certain class. If this is the case, the container should get the class "ok"; Otherwise it should get the class "notok".

In this example I want to check if all "something" elements of the container "content" have the class "anything". The first element should be ignored.

```
<div class="content"> // will get the class "ok"
    <div class="something"></div>
    <div class="something anything"></div>
    <div class="something anything"></div>
    <div class="something anything"></div>
    <div class="something anything"></div>
</div>
```

The above should be ok.

While this one shouldn't be ok, as there is a element with a missing "anyting"-class:

```
<div class="content"> // will get the class "notok"
    <div class="something"></div>
    <div class="something anything"></div>
    <div class="something anything"></div>
    <div class="something"></div>
    <div class="something anything"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to solve that with `each()` but I failed with that because of the exception with the first element...

Comment: is it ok if the first element has the anything class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.content').filter(function () {
    return $('div:gt(0).something.anything', this).length == $('div:gt(0)', this).length
}).addClass('ok')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cWJf6/)**

Comment: Only to understand that correctly. How do I have to modify the script if I would like to add the class 'ok' to the header of that main container. Please have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/cWJf6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ret = "ok";
  // Get all divs of content except the first
  $(".content div:gt(0)").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("anything")) {
      ret = "notok";
      return false;
    }
  });
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `.each()` to solve this problem.

To select all children of an element, use `.children()`.  Calling `.each(function(i){})` will iterate over each element and use an iterator, which you can then check if its zero and continue through the loop.

```
$('.content').children().each(function(i) {
   if (i == 0) return true;
   //it will only reach this point on every child except the first
});
```

Working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/zQ7Gu/1/